# Flutter ListView bounces at the bottom but not on the top (iOS)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an app that contains a Widget which presents a `ListView.builder` with some custom Widgets in it (dynamic length).

For some reason, the list bounces perfectly fine on the bottom (over-scroll in the bottom), but does not bonce at the top (on over-scroll in the top).

I've tried to add this line of code:

```
physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics( parent: BouncingScrollPhysics() ),
```

as well as this one:

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() ),
```

But none of them worked.

Does anyone know how can I make the list bounce on both sides?

Comment: If you show us your code it'll make it a lot easier to fix

Comment: By default, ListView over-scrolls on both sides iOS, it must be something else you are doing in your layout that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top doesn't bounce because you set the shrinkWrap property of the listview to true.

Solution: set shrinkWrap to false and wrap your listView with a container() or sizedBox()

Check the video below for illustration.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_f1d0iY0XVOFi2RoCgbohk4CRhT0G08_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Without actually seeing your code, it seems like you're using `shrinkWrap: true` property in your `ListView` which is preventing it to overscroll on the top (bottom works though).

If that's the case, your better bet is to use a `Column` wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView`. Here's the minimal code:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  child: Column(),
)
```